# О моделях памяти в spinlock mutex

Tags: c++, std-atomic

В книге "Параллельное программирование на С++ в действии" приводится пример спинлока.

```
class spinlock_mutex {
    std::atomic_flag flag;
public:
    spinlock_mutex()
        : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}

    void lock() {
        while(flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }

    void unlock() {
        flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

Мне кажется, что операции с атомарным флагом в lock и unlock синхронизировать не обязательно. В unlock флаг просто сбрысывается, а в lock используется цикл с CAS операцией, которая установит флаг только проверив перед этим, что он снят, и сделает это атомарно.
Можно ли здесь в обоих случаях заменить модель памяти на std::memory_order_relaxed?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering

Comment: Понял. Дело не в самих lock и unlock, а в коде, которые они "защищают". Модель acquire release обеспечит "завершение" операций записи внутри защищаемого блока, а relaxed - нет. Спасибо.